# Dropzone.js / Laravel image upload to S3 failing on larger images 500 error

Tags: php, laravel, file-upload, amazon-s3, laravel-5

I have my Laravel site set up and have an image uploading test page.

I am using Dropzone and the AWS S3 package to handle my image uploads to my S3 Bucket.

Locally, using mamp, I can upload any image without any issues. However when pushing to both a shared hosting and also FortRabbit I get 500 / 503 errors when uploading an image over X mb.

An image 330kb uploads fine, but an image that is 1mb / 700kb etc will not work.

The images are a mixture of png and jpg and some work some don't. All I can put it down to is the smaller images are working fine and the ones from my DSLR are failing.

The phpinfo() shows:

[image]

Which to me looks fine?

I am really stuck on where to look to debug this one. Maxfilesize in dropzone is also set as 10mb.

Comment: Do you get a 500-error on your server? Then check your error log to see what the error message is.

Comment: If you are using nginx, you also need to increase post size limit in nginx config file.

Answer (score 1):

Check other php.ini config values, particularly `upload_max_filesize`.